# SQL query subselect from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have two tables in a databse. In both, colum **id** is the key.

```
TABLE 1: users

(int)      (String)
id  |       email     |
------------------------
0   |    one@mail.co  |
1   |    two@mail.co  |
2   |    three@mail.co|
3   |    four@mail.co |
------------------------

TABLE 2: users_availability

(int)      (TIME)            (TIME)
id  |     from_time  |      to_time
---------------------------------------
0   |      12:00     |      14:00     
1   |      11:15     |      15:00     
2   |      13:00     |      14:00     
3   |      11:30     |      14:30     
---------------------------------------
```

**What do I want?**

I need a query which, given an email address in the **users** table (e.g. 'one@mail.co'), returns a list of ids from those users who have a from_time <= than that of the id associated to the email and a to_time >= than that of the id associated to the email.

**Example:**

Given the email 'one@mail.com', the query should return ids 1 and 3.

**What have I tried?**

```
"SELECT user_avaiability.id
            FROM user_avaiability
            INNER JOIN users_availability 
            ON (users_availability.from_time >= (SELECT users.id
                                               FROM users WHERE email='one@gmail.com')
                                               /*lacking reference to from_time*/
            AND users_availability.to_time <= (SELECT users.id
                                               FROM users WHERE email='one@gmail.com'))";
                                               /*lacking reference to to_time*/
```

**Database info:**

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB - Source distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: So the `id` in the `users_availability` table is the `id` for that user in the `users` table, and not it's own key?

Comment: Also, for the sample data, shouldn't `one@mail.co` produce `1` and `3`, not `1` and `2`?

Comment: @JoelCoehoom that is correct, my bad. Thank you.

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to fully understand how the two tables relate to each other. We can infer the `id` in `users_availability` is the same `id` from the `users` table, so `one@mail.co` has an availability from `12:00` to `14:00`.

However, this is not entirely clear from schema or description.

It's much more common in database design for the `id` column in `user_availability` to mean an auto-incrementing key field that is distinct to its own table. If it's meant to be a foreign key to the `users` table, it should be named more like `user_id`.

That said, if we accept the inference as accurate, we can write this query:

```
SELECT ua2.id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_availability ua1 on ua1.id = u.id
INNER JOIN users_availability ua2 ON ua2.from_time <= ua1.from_time 
    and ua2.to_time >= ua1.to_time
WHERE u.email = @email
```